# How to get all links with python selenium in a tbody

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors, webdriver

Here's my python script that allows to search the https://whatsmyname.app/ site and then retrieve the links with this:

```
link = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody")
for row in link:
    href = row.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
```

However, it doesn't work.
I thought of another alternative, let me explain. When it fetches the `<tbody>`, I want it to be able to go to all the class td's and give its link.
I've tried several things like this:

```
for row in driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody"):
    print(row.get_attribute("class"))
```

The link of the website :
https://whatsmyname.app/

But it didn't work again. It prints nothing. Could someone help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You were close enough. The [*locator strategy*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48369043/official-locator-strategies-for-the-webdriver) which you have used:

```
link = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="/html/body/div/div/div[3]/div[2]/div/div[2]/table/tbody")
```

identifies only one single element, i.e. the only `<tbody>` element. Now, the `<tbody>` element neither have the *href* attribute nor the *class* attribute. Hence nothing is printed.

---

### Solution

The *href* attributes are within the descendent `<a>` tags of the forth `<td>` within their ancestor `<tr>` tags. So your effective line of code will be:

- Using *CSS_SELECTOR*:

  ```
  link = driver.find_elements(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value="table#collectiontable > tbody tr td:nth-child(4)")
  for row in link:
    href = row.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
  ```
- Using *XPATH*:

  ```
  link = driver.find_elements(by=By.XPATH, value="//table[@id='collectiontable']/tbody//tr//following::td[4]/a")
  for row in link:
    href = row.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
  ```

---

Inducing [WebDriverWait](https://stackoverflow.com/a/59130336/7429447) for [*visibility_of_all_elements_located()*](https://stackoverflow.com/a/64770041/7429447) your optimized code block can be:

```
driver.get("https://whatsmyname.app/")
WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//textarea[@id='targetUsername']"))).send_keys("Look")
driver.find_element(By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-success']/i").click()
time.sleep(10)
print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "table#collectiontable > tbody tr td:nth-child(4) > a")))])
print([my_elem.get_attribute("href") for my_elem in WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='collectiontable']/tbody//tr//following::td[4]/a")))])
driver.quit()
```

**Note** : You have to add the following imports :

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
```

Console Output:

```
['http://1001mem.ru/Look', 'https://forum.3dnews.tech/member.php?username=Look', 'https://3dtoday.ru/blogs/Look', 'https://www.7cups.com/@Look', 'https://about.me/Look', 'https://uk.advfn.com/forum/profile/Look', 'https://akniga.org/profile/Look', 'https://projecthub.arduino.cc/Look', 'https://ask.fm/Look', 'https://au.ru/user/Look/', 'https://community.avid.com/members/Look/default.aspx', 'https://forums.babypips.com/u/Look/summary', 'https://bandcamp.com/Look', 'https://www.bandlab.com/Look', 'https://www.babyblog.ru/user/Look', 'https://www.behance.net/Look', 'https://www.bigo.tv/user/Look', 'https://www.bitchute.com/channel/Look/', 'https://blip.fm/Look', 'http://look.blogspot.com/', 'http://bodyspace.bodybuilding.com/Look/', 'https://www.buymeacoffee.com/Look', 'https://www.buzzfeed.com/Look', 'https://cafecito.app/Look', 'https://calendly.com/Look', 'https://look.carbonmade.com/', 'https://career.habr.com/Look', 'https://www.castingcall.club/Look', 'https://www.cda.pl/Look', 'https://forum.cfx.re/u/Look/summary', 'https://www.championat.com/user/Look/', 'https://profile.cheezburger.com/Look', 'https://www.chess.com/member/Look', 'https://chomikuj.pl/Look/', 'https://codeforces.com/profile/Look', 'https://coderwall.com/Look/', 'https://www.coroflot.com/Look', 'https://www.cracked.com/members/Look', 'https://crowdin.com/profile/Look', 'https://cults3d.com/en/users/Look/creations', 'https://darudar.org/users/Look/', 'https://demotywatory.pl/user/Look', 'https://www.designspiration.com/Look/', 'https://dev.to/Look', 'https://www.discogs.com/user/Look', 'https://www.donationalerts.com/r/Look', 'https://www.duolingo.com/profile/Look', 'https://www.ebay.com/str/Look', 'https://f3.cool/Look', 'https://www.fabswingers.com/profile/Look']
```

Answer (score 0):

**Refer the below working code with explanation:**

```
import time

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get('https://whatsmyname.app/')
driver.maximize_window()
# set explicit wait of 20 seconds
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 20)
# send text "test" into search textbox
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.ID, "targetUsername"))).send_keys("test")
# Click on Search button
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, "//button[@class='btn btn-success']"))).click()
time.sleep(6)
# Store all the <a> nodes which contain href
links = wait.until(EC.visibility_of_all_elements_located((By.XPATH, "//table[@id='collectiontable']//td[4]//a")))
# iterate over each entry and print it's href
for row in links:
    href = row.get_attribute("href")
    print(href)
```

**Console result:**

```
http://1001mem.ru/test
https://www.21buttons.com/buttoner/test
https://forum.3dnews.tech/member.php?username=test
https://3dtoday.ru/blogs/test
https://www.7cups.com/@test
https://7dach.ru/profile/test
https://www.aahachat.org/profile/test/
https://about.me/test
https://support.advancedcustomfields.com/forums/users/test/
https://uk.advfn.com/forum/profile/test
https://www.airliners.net/user/test/profile
https://akniga.org/profile/test
https://albicla.com/test
https://www.alik.cz/u/test
https://allesovercrypto.nl/user/test
https://allmylinks.com/test
https://www.americanthinker.com/author/test/
https://apteka.ee/user/id/test
https://projecthub.arduino.cc/test
https://artistsnclients.com/people/test
https://asciinema.org/~test
https://ask.fm/test
https://au.ru/user/test/
https://community.avid.com/members/test/default.aspx
https://forums.babypips.com/u/test/summary
https://bandcamp.com/test
https://www.babyblog.ru/user/test
https://www.behance.net/test
https://www.bigo.tv/user/test
https://www.bikemap.net/en/u/test/routes/created/
http://blogmarks.net/user/test
http://test.blogspot.com/
http://bodyspace.bodybuilding.com/test/
https://boosty.to/test
https://community.bunpro.jp/u/test.json
https://cafecito.app/test
https://test.carbonmade.com/
https://career.habr.com/test
https://test.carrd.co/
https://cash.app/$test
https://www.castingcall.club/test
https://forum.cfx.re/u/test/summary
https://www.championat.com/user/test/
https://www.chamsko.pl/profil/test
https://www.chess.com/member/test
https://chomikuj.pl/test/
https://codeforces.com/profile/test
https://www.codementor.io/@test
https://coderwall.com/test/
https://www.colourlovers.com/lover/test

Process finished with exit code 0
```